# How to convert mat to array2d<rgb_pixel>?

Tags: c++, opencv, image-processing, rgb, mat

I created dll for the [dlib](http://dlib.net/face_landmark_detection_ex.cpp.html) face landmark code there used array2d to get the image, but i like to read an image using Mat and to convert to array2d because dlib supports only array2d. Can any one say how to convert mat to array2d ??

Answer (score 8):

Convert a **cv::Mat** image to **dlib::array2d**:

In case of a BGR image, you can follow this:

```
dlib::array2d<dlib::bgr_pixel> dlibImage;
dlib::assign_image(dlibImage, dlib::cv_image<dlib::bgr_pixel>(cvMatImage));
```

And, if you have a grayscale image, simply use `<unsigned char>` instead of `<bgr_pixel>`:

```
dlib::array2d<unsigned char> dlibImageGray;
dlib::assign_image(dlibImageGray, dlib::cv_image<unsigned char>(cvMatImageGray));
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly convert the Mat to cv_image of dlib. Then using the assign_image() of dlib you can convert the cv_image to array2d.

Answer (score 1):

```
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h" // shame, but needed for using dlib
#include <dlib/image_processing.h>
#include <dlib/opencv/cv_image.h>

dlib::shape_predictor sp;
dlib::deserialize(path_to_landmark_model) >> sp;

cv::Rect r;
cv::Mat I;
dlib::rectangle rec(r.x, r.y, r.x+r.width, r.y+r.height);
dlib::full_object_detection shape = sp(dlib::cv_image<uchar>(I), rec);
```

Comment: i edited my question sir,can u please say the necessary steps

Comment: maybe i misunderstood you, but use a `dlib::cv_image<uchar>(Mat)` . look at last line of code.

Comment: thank u ...i did like
cv::Mat src = cv::imread("image_path",1);
img=dlib::cv_image<uchar>(src);
buti got the error like this Mr.berak **error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel>' and 'dlib::cv_image<unsigned char>')**

Comment: I used it but i got the same error  ** error: no match for 'operator=' (operand types are 'dlib::array2d<dlib::rgb_pixel>' and 'dlib::cv_image<unsigned char>')**   the full code can be viewed by clicking. [click_here](https://jayabalaji1394.wordpress.com/2015/03/18/code-used/)

Comment: I got the issue as ** "pixel type given doesn't match pixel used by the open cv Mat object"** when i used like this                                                      Mat src = imread(argv[1],CV_LOAD_IMAGE_COLOR);
cv_image<rgb_pixel> img(src);
load_bmp(img,"input.bmp");     can u suggest some ideas

Comment: again, you will need a **grayscale** image to get the landmarks

Comment: even i got the same error when i used a gray scale image  Mr.berak, please help me in solving that issue